# How can I stop/start a java application from the command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

I've got a Java application, that I startup from the command prompt using a `.bat` file, contents look as follows :

```
cls
rem Starting app
set CLASSPATH=.;.\lib\
title App1 starting
java app/StartMe
```

It will then startup, and print output to the command window. If I want to stop the app I have to `Control + C`, and type `Y`. This is quite annoying, as I want to start/stop in a loop and I currently have to do this manually

How can I introduce a pause of 30 seconds, and then stop the Java app?

I've tried appending `exit /B` to the above script, but that doesn't seem to do anything, what can I do to add a wait/sleep, and then stop the Java process?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crude way is to `ping` localhost and redirect the output to `NUL` to suppress the output.

```
ping localhost -n 31 >NUL
```

You will need to alter your script as well:

```
cls
rem Starting app
set CLASSPATH=.;.\lib\
title App1 starting
start java app/StartMe
ping localhost -n 31 >NUL
taskkill /F /IM java.exe
```

So this script will start your java app, wait for 30 seconds and kill the java process